# What should be explicitly stated in the contract if the job is going to be done remotely?

Tags: contracts, germany, remote-work

I am about to sign a contract with a company for which I'm going to work remotely. There could be meetings once per month, but the rest of the job is going to be done as a home office. This is going to be my long-term work routine (even after COVID) with this company.

I read the contract, but it was one of the routine contracts that they may have used before the COVID time, without any specification about remote work regulations. It doesn't even specify if I need to work from the office inside the company.

I asked them and they said they handle it as the internal work routine which will be coordinated with the supervisor. But, I'm not sure if it is legally safe to not define the remote work conditions in the contract.

Comment: will you do remote work during covid and office afterwards, or is the expectation that you do remote work post covid?

Comment: @Benjamin permanently.

Comment: Is this actually a contract or is it an offer letter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What should be explicitly stated in the contract if the job is going to be done remotely?

If the guarantee of remote work is a major factor in you signing the contract then the language of the contract needs to explicitly state that you will be working remote.

Ask the company to add an amendment to the contract regarding your remote work.  If they are unwilling to make this simple change then I would reconsider joining this company.  By signing the contract without a remote work provision, you run the risk of having this benefit taken away from you in the future ( or never given to you ) with no protection for yourself.

> I asked them and they said they handle it as the internal work routine which will be coordinated with the supervisor. But, I'm not sure if it is legally safe to not define the remote work conditions in the contract.

You are correct, this is not safe.  If it is not in writing, then assume it does not exist.  Best case scenario this company is lazy and doesn't want to change their contracts, worst case scenario they are attempting to deceive you.  I would be very wary of signing the contract as is.

Comment: They asked for how much mobility I can provide if in occasional cases they require me to be there. I imagined anything more than 3 days per month could mean that I need to go there once per week. I'm not sure if such a term is common to be added to such contracts.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is static in today`s world, everything is fluid :)

In standard contract there is an appendix description clause.
You can ask to create Appendix A or any other letter defining work as remote, even write the clause yourself if they dont have it.

If you want to go with this company, doesn't want to "rattle the boat" and think that position remote definition will make you feel more assured in its remote only nature,
I will suggest asking for the work responsibilities email / document where remote work and office visits schedule outlined.

But, IMHO, even in this case you are not assured remote nature of work.

Every contract have unforeseen and termination clauses that can force you to go to the office if company wants it.
Also, position can be restructured or terminated and internal one opened with same responsibilities and salary but requiring office presence on a regular basis.

Comment: You can't be forced to go to the office if the contract says otherwise.  You can be let go if you don't, but in most of the US (unless a contract says otherwise) you can always be let go.  Having remote work in the contract means that, if the company tries to force you to go in to the office, it's clearly not in any way your fault.

Comment: @DavidThornley i agree. but as i stated below, there are numerous ways to make it instead of forcing it. This is why i suggested to OP that its kind of choice between pushing for work or pushing for contract :)